# Parent directory of Xcode param ${PROJECT_DIR}

Tags: xcode, environment-variables, dir, cp

Hopefully a lightweight question, but I haven't been able to find an answer....I need to write a script for my Xcode project that copies files from a directory a couple of levels above my project directory.

I don't know enough about writing these scripts to get to the parent of the environment variable. I tried

```
${PROJECT_DIR}/../../my-source-folder/
```

But that didn't work.

Comment: Did you find the answer? Could you paste the sollution?

Answer (score 8):

this solution worked fine for me:

```
$(PROJECT_DIR)/../
```